# Evaluating $f(x) = f(0) + xf'(0) + \int_{0}^{x}f''(t)(x-t)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Suppose that a function $f$ has derivatives of all orders near $x=0$.
>
> By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
>
> $f(x)-f(0)= \int_{0}^{x} f'(t)dt$
>
> a. Evaluate the integral using integration by parts to show that
>
> $f(x) = f(0) + xf'(0) + \int_{0}^{x}f''(t)(x-t)dt$
>
> b. Show that integration by parts n times gives
>
> $f(x) = f(0) + xf'(0) (1/(2!))x^2f''(0) + ... + (1/(2!))x^nf^{(n)}(0))+ (1/(2!))\int_{0}^{x}f^{(n+1)}(x-t)^ndt$

So far for part a I'm hitting a dead end with my integration by parts and end up with

$f(0)+xf'(0)+f(x)-x-f(0)+f'(t)(x-t)$

$=xf'(0)+f(x)+f'(t)(x-t)$

I'm assuming I was supposed to end up with f(x) on the right hand side by elimination, but I can't figure out how I'm integrating incorrectly. (I started with $u = (x-t), du = -1, dv = f''(t), v=f'(t)$ for $\int_{0}^{x}f''(t)(x-t)$, if that makes my incorrect result any clearer.)

Any help in the right direction for a and b would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts gives you $$\int_0^x f''(t)(x-t) \, dt = f'(t)(x-t) \bigg|_0^x + \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt$$
where
$$f'(t)(x-t) \bigg|_0^x = f'(x) \cdot 0 - f'(0) \cdot x$$
and
$$ \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt = f(x) - f(0).$$ Thus $$\int_0^x f''(t)(x-t) \, dt = f(x) - f(0) - x f'(0).$$

Comment: I see where my error was now, making du = -1 and forgetting about expressing the first part of the integration ( $f'(t)(x-t)$) in terms of x and 0. Thank you. 
Do you have any idea how I would even begin part b? I figured the terms would begin to cancel each other out leaving f(x), but I'm not sure how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

$f'(t)(x-t)$ should be evaluated at $t=x$ and $t=0$.  There shouldn't be any $t$ left after you do the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Using parts as you said, 
$$
\int_0^xf'(t)dt=\left.\vphantom{\int}-f'(t)\,(x-t)\right|_0^x-\int_0^xf''(t)\,(t-x)\,dt=f'(0)\,x+\int_0^xf''(t)\,(x-t)\,dt
$$